Handle getting and executing upon the results using a Java Map
I feel like there must be a better way to handle getting and processing, but I'm not seeing anything.
My code is littered with null checks immediately before "doing the thing"
Map<Integer, Animal> zoo = new HashMap();

..... Fill zoo .....

Animal a = zoo.get(id);
if(a != null) {
    a.feed(food);
}

Is there some way to better process this? Such as
zoo.getAndUse(id, animal -> animal.feed(food));


You might use Animal a = zoo.getOrDefault(id, new Animal()): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-

Animal a = zoo.computeIfAbsent(id, i -> new Animal()); will be better because you will create a new instance of Animal only if you need it.

I don't think creating/inserting new instances is part of the problem.  @ browsermator @ Megaprog

What about this:
Optional.ofNullable( zoo.get( id ) )
    .ifPresent( animal -> animal.feed( food ) );

Ok, using Optional is here just another kind of null-check …
Or you wrap it into a method:
public final void feed( final AnimalId id, final Food food )
{
    final var animal = zoo.get( id );
    if( nonNull( animal ) animal.feed( food );
}

This just moves the null-check to another location, and it makes sense only when your code has many animals to feed. Unfortunally, you have to write an new wrapper method for each and every operation you want to perform on the Animal instances.
So what about your own enhanced implementation of Map:
public interface NullSafeMap<K,V> extends Map<K,V>
{
    public default <A> void getAndDo( final K key, final A argument, final BiConsumer<V,A> process )
    {
        final var value = get( key );
        if( nonNull( value ) ) process.accept( value, argument );
    }

    public default Optional<V> optionalGet( final K key )
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable( get( key ) );
    }

    public default <A> Optional<V> optionalGetAndDo( final K key, final A argument, final BiConsumer<V,A> process )
    {
        final var value = optionalGet( key );
        value.ifPresent( v -> process.accept( v, argument ) );
        return value;
    }

    //---* The method you suggested *-------------------------------
    public default void getAndUse( final K key, final Consumer<V> process )
    {
        final var value = get( key );
        if( nonNull( value ) ) process.accept( value );
    }
}

public class NullSafeHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> implements NullSafeMap<K,V>
{
    public NullSafeHashMap() { super(); }
}

final var zoo = new NullSafeHashMap<AninmalId,Animal>();
final var food = new Food();
zoo.getAndDo( id, food, Animal::feed );
zoo.optionalGet( id ).ifPresent( animal -> animal.feed( food ) );
final var fedAnimal = zoo.optionalGetAndDo( id, food, Animal::feed );
fedAnimal.ifPresent( animal::walk );
zoo.getAndUse( id, animal -> animal.feed( food ) );

Obviously you can add several more methods to the NullSafeMap interface …

Fantastic write up. The enhanced Map handles things that will happen as well as removes about 500 null checks and their unit tests. The exception issues with Consumer are problematic (thanks to @rzwitserloot 's answer!) but given trivial processing inside of the Consumer this seems like a great easy enhancement

Write your own implementation of Consumer that throws an unchecked exception, wrapping any checked exception thrown inside, and you addressed even that issue. But from your sample call, this was not a requirement.

You could avoid declaring a variable outside the if statement with pattern matching for instanceof.
if (zoo.get(id) instanceof Animal a) 
    a.feed(food);


The computeIfPresent could be used if the mapping function returned the present value each time:
zoo.computeIfPresent(id, (k, animal) -> {animal.feed(food); return animal;});

The above would be simpler to write if the feed method was declared to return this;:
zoo.computeIfPresent(id, (k, animal) -> animal.feed(food));


You have a few options:
Default behaviour
If you lookup a key in a map to then act on an object, and you want to act on a default object instead if the key is not there, that's easy:
map.getOrDefault(a, SCAPEGOAT).feed(food);

Calculate-as-needed
If you lookup a key in a map to then act on an object, and you want to create the key/value mapping if it isn't already in the map, you can do that:
var animalSounds = new HashMap<AnimalType, String>();
String sound = animalSounds.computeIfAbsent(animalType,
  t -> animalSoundsLookupService.lookup(t, apiKey));

This will lookup the animal sound only if it hasn't already been looked up, and the result of this method is the animal sound - from the map itself if the key was already in there, and the result of lookup if otherwise.
Lambdas (very slightly) bad
Lambda blocks are non-transparent in 3 crucial ways. I will illustrate the problems here, with the assumption that map.getAndUse exists (It doesn't, but, let's hypothetically imagine it does):

They aren't transparent in regards to control flow.

In other words, this is not legal java code:
zoo.getAndUse(id, animal -> {
  if (animal.getColor() == Color.BROWN) return animal;
});

return somethingElse;

It wouldn't compile because you can't use control flow statements ('return', 'break', 'continue') to jump across a lambda boundary.

Checked exceptions

This isn't legal either:
try {
  zoo.getAndUse(id, animal -> writeToFile(animal));
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new SaveGameException("Can't save animal", e);
}

You'd think it should be - any IOException thrown by writeToFile is caught, after all. But no - lambda do not let you get around a 'must catch checked exception requirement' by catching  it outside the lambda.

mutable local variables

int countSilent = 0;
animals.forEach(animal -> countSilent += (animal.getSound() != null) ? 1 : 0);

Sure, there are fairly obvious alternatives for all of these. Such as animals.stream().filter(a -> animal.getSound() != null).count();.
However, there isn't always an alternative, and these transparency issues are just straight up annoying.
Hence, lambdas bad - just, very slightly bad. Often lambdas are the least problematic way to solve a problem, thus, it wins, despite the fact that they stumble right out of the gate.
This, in some ways, actually makes sense. Because these 3 transparency problems actually turn into upside if the lambda 'travels' - if the lambda is executed later (after the code flows out of the context the lambda lexicographically appears in), or is executed in another thread, all 3 of the above items actually are great. Java can't transport an exception thrown by a lambda to the catch block in a method that was executed 4 hours ago, in a different thread, and which has long since returned. What would that even mean? - just one example. mutable local variables: Does that now mean we can make those volatile, because we can now run into threading issues with em? That sounds annoying. And so on.
Hence, the value of a hypothetical getAndUse is dubious. Any usage of a lambda in a context where it wouldn't travel is handicapped, so, think twice before adding it. Even if it's great for the one use case you are thinking of, consider that a great many usecases are seriously aggravating - for example, if the body throws IOExceptions, this is just an open invitation to a 'there are multiple ways to write code that does the exact same thing' style debate.
Don't hack your way around it
Trying to use merge or computeIfPresent or similar to then 'compute' the new value as simply the old value is a really bad idea. That's because comments are evil. Yet again, very very often the lesser evil, but this:
// this doesn't actually compute at all, just trying to avoid creating a local var and an 'if' check
zoo.computeIfPresent(id, (k, animal) -> stuff);

is vastly inferior to:
Animal a = zoo.get(k);
if (a != null) stuff;

And, of course, without that comment, the code is lying to you. The code contains the very word 'compute' when it computes nothing. Hence, do not hack it. It's bad code style.
A simple solution
Often the only thing that is bothering you is an outdated style guide. Think about it. A style guide that says this is illegal:
Animal a = zoo.get(id);
// illegal: all 'if' MUST have braces
if (a != null) a.feed(food);

and also says this is fine:
list.stream().filter(x -> !x.isFoo()).forEach(x -> bar(x));

is a dumb style guide you need to ignore. Any argument you care to brandish to explain why 'braceless' single-statement if/for/while is a bad idea works just as well, if not better, against using braceless lambdas. (Arguments such as: "What if you want to add a log line?" or "What if the person reading the code is unbelievably dense and somehow fails to realize we've gotten into a code flow point, where some line may run never, once, or multiple times relative to its outer context?").
Once you ditch the rule and embrace (heh) braceless if/for/while (of course, only in those cases where the body is simple, obvious, and short - pretty much the same rule that's commonly applied to lambdas. Use your common sense - you have it, or, you should be nowhere near the code base in the first place), this question tends to disappear as a concern.
If your primary concern is the 'polluting' of the context with a new variable, java allows code blocks anywhere. This is legal:
AnimalSound sound; {
  Animal a = zoo.get(id);
  if (a != null) a.feed(food);
  sound = a == null ? SILENCE : a.getSound();
}
// a does not exist here, at all.

.. and avoids the problem.
